# Image and Title in UIButton

Tags: swift, uibutton

I am configuring my tableview cell like I mentioned below. It works, but the problem is there is unwanted space before the title 'Closed' since I am removing the image. How do I remove the unwanted space, so that my 'Closed' title will be centered?

```
if (condition) {
  self.myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "activeImage"), forState: .Normal)
  self.myButton.setTitle("Active", forState: .Normal)
} 
else {
  self.myButton.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
  self.myButton.setTitle("Closed", forState: .Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing this in else condition

```
self.myButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .Center
self.myButton.contentVerticalAlignment = .Center
```